# Map JS array and pass variable into JSON output

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, array-map

I have an array `let labels = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear']`.

I want to map the array to a JSON output `{'Apple':0, 'Banana':0, 'Pear':0}`.

I am using the script:

```
let output = labels.map(function(item) {
  return { item: 0 };
});
```

which gives me:

```
[{"item": 0}, {"item": 0}, {"item": 0}]
```

How do I pass the variable item into the JSON output?

Comment: use `return ({[item]: 0});`.

Comment: welcome. Placing `square brackets`, will retrieve value of the variable `item`, otherwise it will treat as a string.

Comment: @random I realised I made a mistake in the question. How do I get a JSON output as follow: `{"Apple": 0, "Banana": 0, "Pear": 0}`? I probably can't use .map() as it gives me an array?

Comment: No issues. use `reduce` which is more appropriate for converting `multiple into one object`-> `console.log(labels.reduce((a, item) => {a[item]=0; return a}, {}));`